# Mongoose: sort query results by least occurences of word in array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of videos :

```
var VideoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: {
    type: String, required : true
  },
  orderBy: {
    type: Number
  },
  views: [{
    type: String
  }]
});
```

'orderBy' lets me define the order in which I serve videos

'views' is a list of usernames, those who have watched the video.

I want to keep users from watching again the same video until they have watched all videos in the collection. So I keep the names of users who have watched the video inside the 'views'.

Now I query for videos using 'sort'.

```
return this.find(videoQuery)
.skip(offset)
.limit(count || 10) // @todo 10 : param
.sort({views: {$meta: username}, 'orderBy': -1})
.exec();
```

And I get the error message :

```
Can't canonicalize query: BadValue bad sort specification
```

Can you help ?

Comment: I believe I can only use 'textScore' as value for $meta, and so it is useless for my usecase : the parameters in query are not the ones I want to 'textScore', I just want the username.

I have looked for hours but I can't seem to find a solution on mongodb docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be wrong but from mongo docs. When you specify $meta in sort you need to include it in projectedFieldName.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/#proj._S_meta

So it should looks something like this

`return this.find(videoQuery, { views: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
.skip(offset)
.limit(count || 10) // @todo 10 : param
.sort({views: {$meta: textScore}, 'orderBy': -1})
.exec();`

**UPDATED**
Seems that $meta only accepts 'textScore' as @Pierre mentioned.

So another suggestion is to use underscore or native js to sort data when response comes from DB. This will be less efficient and may need some adjustments, but this will work definitely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, yout got me a step further. I got a new error : Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unsupported $meta operator: 'username'

I believe I can only use 'textScore' as value for $meta, and so it is useless for my usecase : the parameters in query are not the ones I want to 'textScore', I just want the username.

I have looked for hours but I can't seem to find a solution on mongodb docs.

Comment: Well if that is the case than its bad and $meta operator needs more functionality((((.

Comment: Btw..Maybe you sort them when response comes from DB.. With JS i think it's will be pretty easy, using underscore.. or native js.